# Multiple requests from different components in Vue - best practice

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My app consumes an self made - HTTP REST API. I use vueX for state management.

I have some nested components that needs access to the same http result as the parent, but I also use the component in other places where the parent does not fetch the result. Is there a way (pattern) to make sure a resource is not fetched multiple times.

I found this, and like the way of doing things, but I can't figure out how to make a new request to the server for updating the result. https://tkacz.pro/use-vuex-to-avoid-multiple-requests-from-different-components/

and is this even best practice ?

anyone has a better way ?

Comment: *I can't figure out how to make a new request to the server for updating the result* - add a parameter to actions, like `refresh`.

Comment: Year, I have thought about that, but I wanted a more clean and generic solution. What if the action takes other arguments? then is not that clear. ( make sense ) ;). I also come up with a solution with another action "clear()" that set the list til empty [] .. but I hoped for at better pattern.

Comment: If an unspecified amount of arguments is expected, use one `options` argument instead of multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Using vuex and checking if your state is already populated is good enough. If it's not, then call a [vuex `action`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html). It will help you to have a state shared globally in your app.

Not sure about this part

> how to make a new request to the server for updating the result

What would be the issue or calling the API a second time? If needed, you can use the suggested solution in the comment, like adding a `?refresh` or even and id to it `id={randomId}`.

Comment: The problem I referred applies to Vuex and action params, in this case an action caches the result and doesn't reach the point where it HTTP params could be used.

Comment: Never heard of any cache on Vuex. For me, if you call an action, it will always reach the server. This is the default behavior, are you sure? (have to admit that I'm doing a lot of GraphQL lately so you're maybe right)

Comment: The technique is described in the article that the OP linked.

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad, didn't paid more attention!